# What is the difference between (defn function-name) and (defn- function-name in clojure?

Tags: clojure

Can someone explain this to me? I think I understand that (defn -main) is declaring a main method that would be recognised by Java and that if you use this in conjunction with a namespace with (:gen-class) that you can fool Java into thinking clojure is object oriented, however I can't work out what the purpose is if you just create a function like

(def- add2
    (partial + 2)
)

or (defn- my-function...)

Can anyone explain this simply or correct me if the above assumptions are wrong?

**Edit - I understand what a partial function does :) I'm just wondering if there's a difference between above and (def add2 (partial + 2))

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Functions defined with `defn-` aren't accessible outside of the namespace they were defined in. In other words, they are *private*.

Take a look at the [source of defn-](http://www.clodoc.org/doc/clojure.core/defn-). This macro evaluates to a call to `defn` with `{:private true}` merged into the metadata hash.

Comment: That's great, thanks for the quick reply(12 mins to accept answer)

Comment: Even better, using (source) hadn't occurred to me as I assumed it would have given me the source of (defn) and that - was a special operator